# Yes another ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql, on-duplicate-key

I've been reading all the questions on here but I still don't get it

I have two identical tables of considerable size. I would like to update table `packages_sorted` with data from `packages_sorted_temp` without destroying the existing data on `packages_sorted`

Table `packages_sorted_temp` contains data on only 2 columns `db_id` and `quality_rank`

Table `packages_sorted` contains data on all 35 columns but `quality_rank` is 0

The primary key on each table is `db_id` and this is what I want to trigger the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with.

In essence how do I merge these two tables by and change `packages_sorted`.`quality_rank` of 0 to the `quality_rank` stored in `packages_sorted_temp` under the same primary key

Here's what's not working

```
INSERT INTO `packages_sorted` ( `db_id` , `quality_rank` )
SELECT `db_id` , `quality_rank`
FROM `packages_sorted_temp` ON DUPLICATE
KEY UPDATE `packages_sorted`.`db_id` = `packages_sorted`.`db_id`
```

Comment: Is this related to php? i.e. does it work from MySQL workbench and not from php? if so, php tag can be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update packages_sorted , packages_sorted_temp 
set packages_sorted.quality_rank = packages_sorted_temp.quality_rank 
where packages_sorted.db_id = packages_sorted_temp.db_id
```

Comment: @MGA I just realize that the previous SQL does not work on mysql. I pretty sure that it works on Oracle. So, I have fixed this for mysql format.

Comment: Ok Still +1,sorry for that, but didn't you need to join the two tables?

Comment: Thanks, this one seems to work faster although only slightly on a small test set of 1M rows. It's also a bit easier to understand for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Update join like this:

```
Update packages_sorted p
    inner join packages_sorted_temp temp
    on p.db_id = temp.db_id 
set p.db_id = temp.db_id, p.quality_rank = temp.quality_rank
```